# How to log the SQL Job failure to the Log Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Jobs are running from the SQL Agent. At this moment, we don't have the Email Notification configured for failure from the SQL Job.

I am considering to fetch the errors from the log table. Further then to have a stored procedure to generate the error report.

```
select  top 10 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
```

How to log the SQL Job failure to the Log Table? What will happen, when a job is scheduled to run for every 5 mins and the error will get updated (or) error will get inserted as new record?

[image]

Comment: you might want to look at this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177204/sql-agent-job-logs-cant-get-the-error-log

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f3758b95-2a76-4f3b-82f8-d0a5b8c4b8b0/sql-server-job-fail-how-to-log-event-in-sql-server-error-log?forum=sqlgetstarted

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Open Properties of job
- Go under Steps
- Get into the step by pressing Edit button
- Navigate under Advanced
- Change the on Failure Action to `Quit the job reporting failure`
- Then Check Log To table

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the limitations of the built-in logs, job history, etc., where it doesn't capture when a step fails, but the job itself doesn't.

Based upon this [sqlshack article](https://www.sqlshack.com/reporting-and-alerting-on-job-failure-in-sql-server/), I built and implemented something very similar which maintains a permanent history of job/step failures, etc., even if you delete a job/step.  This solution will even notify when this job fails.

Best of luck!